# How to overwrite previously dual booted Ubuntu with fresh install?

Tags: dual-boot, reinstall

I have a dual booted Ubuntu 19.10 with Windows 10. I recently started facing a lot of problems with drivers which couldn't be resolved. I want a complete fresh install for Ubuntu 19.10. How do I do this process without harming Windows and keeping the sytem dual booted? Do I first need to somehow remove my current Ubuntu and then reinstall. Or is there a way to overwrite it?

Comment: You will overwrite the previous install, just repeat the installation process!

Comment: If you boot from the Ubuntu Live USB/DVD and start the install process, you should see an option to do what you want. If you don't see the option to install Ubuntu replacing the existing version, then please take a screenshot of the installation screen and add it to your question.

Comment: You don't have to "remove" first. Although, during the installation process, you may want to format the partition where you will reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks all! 
Repeating the USB installation gave me the option to reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

From Windows, you can delete the partition, re-create the partition, then reinstall. I did this a few weeks ago.

Comment: I went with repeating the installation process and it erased the previous install for me!